# How to use vagrant docker-run with container environment variable expansion

Tags: mongodb, docker, vagrant, vagrant-windows

I'm using vagrant and docker on a Windows 7 machine with VirtualBox as a provider for the docker host VM. I have a vagrant project defined with the `docker` provider so that `vagrant up` will start the `mongo` container. I am not provisioning the `mongo` container in the docker host VM because I will sometimes want `mongo`, sometimes `postgres`, etc.

For the `mongo` case, I'm trying to run some mongo collection initialization scripts against this running `mongo` container to set up indexes and the like using vagrant. The `mongo` image does not run anything other than `mongod`, so `has_ssh` is `false` for the container, so using provisioners to run these operations is not an option.

I've tried running the mongo shell in a separate container linked to the container running `mongodb`, but for that to work, I need to be able to expand the `mongo` environment variables (`MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR` and `MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_PORT`) at the time the command runs in the container.

I've been trying to do this using `vagrant docker-run`, but I can't find a way to get the command interpreted properly such that these environment variables are expanded correctly. Each attempt has resulted in the `mongo` command complaining that the host and port have not been provided (the environment variables expand to empty).

What I'd eventually like to be able to do is:

1. start a container linked to the running mongo container (so it gets its env variables)
2. upload a javascript file to the new container that includes the mongo initialization I'd like to do
3. run a shell command on the container like so:

`mongo "$MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR:$MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_PORT/db-name" initialize.js`

4. remove the container

Any suggestions or other approaches I could try?

## Example of a typical failed command

Powershell is the command line interpreter on this Windows system:

```
PS C:\Users\hoobajoob\Documents\Eclipse\workspace-sts-luna\project\.environment\vagrant\mongo-provisioner> vagrant docker-run default -- mongo
 '$MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR:`$MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_PORT/test' --eval "printjson(db.getCollectionNames())"
==> default: Docker host is required. One will be created if necessary...
    default: Docker host VM is already ready.
==> default: Creating the container...
    default:   Name: mongo-provisioner_default_1449193166_1449193166
    default:  Image: mongo
    default:    Cmd: mongo $MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR:$MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_PORT/test
    default:   Link: mongo-container:mongo
    default:

    default: Container is starting. Output will stream in below...
    default:
    default: MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7
    default: 2015-12-04T01:38:20.037+0000 E QUERY    Error: Missing host name in connection string ":/test"
    default:     at Error (<anonymous>)
    default:     at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:160:15)
    default:     at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:160
    default: exception:
    default: connect failed
    default:
A Docker command executed by Vagrant didn't complete successfully!
The command run along with the output from the command is shown
below.

Command: "docker" "run" "--name" "mongo-provisioner_default_1449193166_1449193166" "--link" "mongo-container:mongo" "--rm=true" "mongo" "mongo" "$MONGO_POR
T_27017_TCP_ADDR:$MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_PORT/test" "--eval" "printjson(db.getCollectionNames())"

Stderr: exception: connect failed

Stdout: MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7
2015-12-04T01:38:20.037+0000 E QUERY    Error: Missing host name in connection string ":/test"
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:160:15)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:160
```

## Sources

The docker host `Vagrantfile`:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.6.0"
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.hostname = "docker-host"
  config.vm.box_check_update = false
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  config.vm.box = "williamyeh/ubuntu-trusty64-docker"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 27017, host: 27017
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
end
```

The `mongod` container `Vagrantfile`:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.6.0"
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'docker'

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  config.vm.provider "docker" do |docker|
    docker.vagrant_vagrantfile = "../docker-host/Vagrantfile"
    docker.image = "mongo"
    docker.ports = ['27017:27017']
    docker.name = 'mongo-container'
  end
end
```

The `mongo shell` container `Vagrantfile` (this is the container against which I'm trying to run `vagrant docker-run` commands such that the mongo environment variables linked to the `mongod` container get expanded correctly):

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Specify Vagrant version and Vagrant API version
Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.6.0"
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'docker'

# Create and configure the Docker container(s)
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  config.vm.provider "docker" do |docker|
    docker.vagrant_vagrantfile = "../docker-host/Vagrantfile"
    docker.image = "mongo"
    docker.link("mongo-container:mongo")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, I'm finding Vagrant's docker provider fairly limited in terms of the range of docker container operations I can perform with it.

I looked into running `ssh` inside the mongo container, which would allow me to run Vagrant's provisioners on the `mongo` container so I could get these scripts to run that way. But, that requires requires a) defining a custom image and reworking the entrypoint so both `ssh` and `mongod` are started, and b) setting `has_ssh=true` in the docker provider `Vagrantfile`.

That option, unfortunately, does not play well with the current version of vagrant, which hangs on my Windows system when I run `vagrant up` if I set `has_ssh` to `true` in a docker provider `Vagrantfile`.

So, for this Vagrant newbie, my options appear to be limited.

I'm currently thinking that a better approach might be to drop the use of both of the docker provider `Vagrantfile` projects altogether, and instead define a bunch of different provisioners in the one docker host `Vagrantfile`.

Then, if I wanted to start up a specific container, I can define and run a provisioner that just runs that container (without performing any mongo initialization). If I want to run these mongo initialization scripts, then I have a separate provisioner that will perform those operations, and so on.

Tearing down a container would then require running `vagrant ssh` with the corresponding `docker rm` command.

It seems a shame to resort to that, but I'm not having much luck trying to get mongo initialized via `vagrant docker-run`.

## Update: 12/4/2015

I abandoned the use of Vagrant's docker provider altogether, mostly due to the fact that, at least in my case, I found that the docker provider is too limited in its supported docker vocabulary to meet my needs. This conclusion is qualified by the fact that I'm not a veteran of either Vagrant or Docker, so it's entirely possible that I missed something.

So for example, in order to initialize mongo databases, I'd prefer to be able to do so using the same javascript initialization files that might be run by a `mongoDB` admin at the target site, and these come from the dev source tree. It's way too much overhead to have to build a custom docker mongo container pre-provisioned with these files.

The Vagrant way, at least so far as I understand it, would be to use a `file` provisioner to copy that file up to the running container and a `script` provisioner to execute it on the container. Vagrant's `file` and `script` provisioners require SSH on the container in order to work.

But, it appears to be [a common recommendation](https://blog.docker.com/2014/06/why-you-dont-need-to-run-sshd-in-docker/) out there in docker land NOT to run SSH in containers for a number of reasons, so I'd prefer not to do that if I don't have to.

The (or one) docker way to achieve this without creating a custom container pre-provisioned with these files would be to use `docker cp <container>` and `docker exec <container>` in order to achieve this on the running container. Neither of these is surfaced by Vagrant's docker provider commands, so I didn't see how I was going to get there via the docker provider.

So, it's completely reasonable, I believe, to use Vagrant's provisioners, but only when interacting with the docker host VM (a VirtualBox box in my case), for which SSH access isn't any kind of controversy (as far as I can tell).

I moved all of the container lifecycle operations - create, start, stop, restart, rm, etc. into provisioners on the `Vagrantfile` configuration for the docker host. To carry out these operations, I stick to the docker cli.

The `Vagrantfile` provisioners on the Docker Host VM look like so:

```
# provisioners
  config.vm.provision "host.provision.scripts.mongo", type: "file", source: $mongoProvisionInit, destination: $hostProvisionMongoInit
  config.vm.provision "mongo.run", type: "shell", inline: $dockerRun_mongo
  config.vm.provision "mongo.provision.scripts", type: "shell", inline: $dockerCp_MongoInit
  config.vm.provision "mongo.db.init", type: "shell", inline: $dockerExec_mongoDbInit
  config.vm.provision "mongo.stop", type: "shell", inline: $dockerStop_mongo
  config.vm.provision "mongo.start", type: "shell", inline: $dockerStart_mongo
  config.vm.provision "mongo.restart", type: "shell", inline: $dockerRestart_mongo
  config.vm.provision "mongo.rm", type: "shell", inline: $dockerRm_mongo
e
```

...and the `inline` scripts look like so:

```
$dockerRun_mongo = <<MONGO
echo '>>> docker run --name mongo-container -p 27017:27017 -d mongo'
docker run --name mongo-container -p 27017:27017 -d mongo
MONGO

$dockerCp_MongoInit = <<MONGO
echo '>>> docker exec mongo-container mkdir /home/vagrant'
docker exec mongo-container mkdir -p /home/vagrant
echo '>>> docker cp ./provision/mongo/initialize.js mongo-container:/home/vagrant/mongo.initialize.js'
docker cp ./provision/mongo/initialize.js mongo-container:/home/vagrant/mongo.initialize.js
MONGO

$dockerExec_mongoDbInit = <<MONGO
echo '>>> docker exec mongo-container mongo mongo db-name /home/vagrant/mongo.initialize.js'
docker exec mongo-container mongo db-name /home/vagrant/mongo.initialize.js
MONGO

$dockerStop_mongo = <<MONGO
echo '>>> docker stop mongo-container'
docker stop mongo-container
MONGO
```

...I then wire all of these up to `gradle` using the vagrant plugin from bmuschko: `'com.bmuschko:gradle-vagrant-plugin:2.0'`. So, then my dev environment can be automated with gradle tasks like `initializeMongoAndRun`, which go off and issue `vagrant provision --provision-with` commands on these different provisioners to get work done.

This means all devs working on this project would all need to agree to host docker in a vm, even on a Linux system. For the benefit of a consistent docker and container experience across machines, this seems like an acceptable tradeoff.

I'll keep my eye on the Vagrant `docker` provider. Perhaps it will become more functional for these types of uses, or I'll figure out what it was I was missing to have made it work.